# using numpy arrays and ctypes for OpenGL calls in Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, numpy, ctypes, pyglet

I've got what seems like a very ugly little piece of code that I seem to keep on resorting back to whenever I'm trying to draw arrays with pyglet, of the form:

```
vertPoints = someArray.flatten().astype(ctypes.c_float)
vertices_gl = vertPoints.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
```

Which I cobbled together based on the few resources I could find using numpy with pyglet.  Is there a more elegant way to get a pointer to a numpy array as c_floats?

Here's the code above in the context of a small example I wrote:

```
import numpy as np; import ctypes
import pyglet; import pyglet.gl as gl

def drawArray(someArray):

    vertPoints = someArray[:,:2].flatten().astype(ctypes.c_float)
    vertices_gl = vertPoints.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))

    vertColors = someArray[:,2:].flatten().astype(ctypes.c_float)
    colors_gl = vertColors.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))

    gl.glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_gl)
    gl.glColorPointer(3,  gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, colors_gl)
    gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_POINTS, 0, len(vertPoints) // 2)

window = pyglet.window.Window(400,400)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    gl.glPointSize(10.0)
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_POINT_SMOOTH)
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
    gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

    points = np.random.random((50,5))*np.array([400,400,1,1,1])
    drawArray(points)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: If you use `dtype=np.float32` and use separate arrays for the vertices and colors, then you don't need to `flatten` (copy the data to contiguous memory) or use `astype` (create a whole new array), and the pointer is just `vertices_gl = verticesArray.ctypes.data`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need to convert the address of data to a float pointer, you can pass the address directly:

```
gl.glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertPoints.ctypes.data)
gl.glColorPointer(3,  gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertColors.ctypes.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Numpy float arrays directly with vertex buffer objects. I haven't used them in the context of Pyglet though. Something like:

```
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo

# setup
vertices_gl = vbo.VBO(vertPoints)
colours_gl = vbo.VBO(vertPoints)

# in drawing code
vertices.bind()
colours.bind()
glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_gl)
glColorPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_gl)
```

Comment: So far as I know, that does work in PyOpenGL, but won't in Pyglet because of the different way that the bindings are generated. PyOpenGL does a lot more for you in terms of facilitating simple interfaces, whereas Pyglet expects things to be passed as ctypes.  While I've considered switch to PyOpenGL for that reason, it's become a curiosity thing at this point; there must be some kind of clean syntax for generating a c_float pointer into a numpy array.